# order of element in commutative group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I'm trying to solve the following:

$H$ a commutative group of order $t = c\cdot d$, where $c$ prime and $d \in \mathbb{N_+}$, $gcd(c,d) =1$. Let $h \in H$ and $h^d \neq 1$. Show that the order of h is a multiple of $c$.

I know that $ord(h) | c\cdot d$ and $h^{cd}=1$, but I don't know how to proceed.

Does anyone have a hint? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Use contradiction. If $c \not \mid o(h)$ then we must have that $o(h)  \mid d$, as $o(h) = c^i \cdot k$, where $i=0$ or $1$ and $k\mid d$.  But this is impossible as then $h^d = 1$

Answer (score 1):

These two facts are very important for this problem: $ord(h)|c⋅d$ and the way we have defined c and d.
Here further deconstructions:

1. Consider that we have $ord(h)|c⋅d$. Recall Euclid's Lemma and the definition of co-primes.

(Also remember $x | a \iff  \exists y\in Z, x*y = a$

2. The definition of $ord(h) = k \iff h^k=1$.

Let me know if you're still having trouble following this and I can give more hints.

Comment: The first fact is not necessarily true if one of the integers $c,d$ isn't prime, so maybe you should add this to make the statement complete

Comment: Yes, I realized my mistake in omitting this, fixed it right after posting :)